# What statistical test is used for simultaneity in time?

Tags: time-series, markov-process

I have a dataset where for each individual there's a record for its behavior, being a state (with start and end times) or an event (duration 0, i.e. an instantaneous behaviour).

[Here is an example of the dataset.](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/13549ff7f716aacfb768ca6b73554e5a/Untitled%20spreadsheet%20-%20Sheet1.csv)

Some of these events can be simultaneous in time (e.g., you can sneeze *while* standing, or while sitting). Others usually happen very close in time, but not necessarily one after the other, there can be some overlapping.

I'd like to analyze this dataset in terms of:

- How many times an event or state is followed by another
- How many times an event or state is simultaneous with another.
- Other cool and sexy stuff with it such as visualizations, etc.

I've never worked with this kind of problem, and I don't know if there's a specific keyword while searching for solutions for this.

Someone suggested to use Markov Chains, but for what I understood only evaluates sequences and not simultaneity.